# How do I clear the value in div (TICTACTOE GAME)

Tags: javascript

I need help in clearing the value in div for my tic tac toe game.

Here's the HTML code I have:

```
<div class="btns">
            <button class="btnstart" id="start">Start game</button><button class="btnrefresh" id="refresh">Refresh</button>
        </div>

        <div class="play-area gray pointerEvents">
            <div id="block_0" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_1" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_2" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_3" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_4" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_5" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_6" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_7" class="block"></div>
            <div id="block_8" class="block"></div>
          </div>
```

Here's my code for putting the X's and O's on the div:

```
boxes.addEventListener('click', e =>{
                //dispalay x and o.
        move++;
                if (turn % 2 === 1){
                    event.target.innerHTML = activePlayer1;
                    turn++;
                }else{
                    event.target.innerHTML = activePlayer2;
                    turn--;
                }
    })
```

Now I want to clear the value in div class block using this code:

```
refreshbtn.addEventListener('click', e =>{
     
        document.querySelector('.block').innerHTML = '';

    })
```

But it seems not to work. :(

Comment: `document.querySelector('.block')` returns only the first element of class `block`. Which block(s) are you trying to clear?

Comment: the blocks on the div class="play-area gray pointerEvents">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`. Since you want to change multiple elements. Then use a loop to change each item

```js
const refreshbtn = document.querySelector("button");
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".block");

refreshbtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  blocks.forEach(block => {
    block.innerHTML = "";
  });
})
```

```html
<div class="block">A</div>
<div class="block">B</div>
<div class="block">C</div>
<div class="block">D</div>
<div class="block">E</div>

<button>Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**document.querySelector('.block')** returns only the first element of class block, so it's **clear only** the div with **id block_0**

Comment: if you wanna start the game from the beginning you can use "location.reload();"